# Есть 2 таблицы с одинаковой структурой. Нужно, что бы при изменении в одной таблице, данные переносились в другую

Tags: javascript, html

Есть файл index.html с таблицой

```
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>№</th> 
                    <th>Фамилия Имя</th> 
                    <th>Очки</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody class="selected"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>1</td> 
                    <td>Williams, Serena</td> 
                    <td>7780</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>2</td> 
                    <td>Kerber, Angelique</td> 
                    <td>7905</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>3</td> 
                    <td>Pliskova, Karolina</td> 
                    <td>5640</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>4</td> 
                    <td>Halep Simona</td> 
                    <td>5172</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
        <a href="rating.html">Показать весь рейтинг</a>
```

В самом низу ссылка на отдельный файл, в котором такая же таблица, только расширенная. (20 участников). Как сделать так, что бы я мог вносить изменения в файл rating.html и у меня автоматически top10 переносилось в файл index.html с учетом изенений? Готов заплатить за решение, iluha0906 скайп.
Вот файл rating.html

```
      <div id="rating" class="rating rating-page"> 
        <table id ="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
            <thead> 
        <tr> 
          <th>№</th> 
          <th>Фамилия Имя</th> 
          <th>Очки</th> 
        </tr> 
      </thead> 
      <tbody class="selected"> 
        <tr> 
          <td>1</td> 
          <td>Мацюк Александр</td> 
          <td>280</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>2</td> 
          <td>Мурзин Максим</td> 
          <td>135</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>3</td> 
          <td>Тюков Владимир</td> 
          <td>85</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>4</td> 
          <td>Гаврилов Константин</td> 
          <td>80</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>5</td> 
          <td>Кутя Сергей</td> 
          <td>80</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>6</td> 
          <td>Кислань Елизавета</td> 
          <td>72</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>7</td> 
          <td>Моисеенко Александр</td> 
          <td>61</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>8</td> 
          <td>Краснов Денис</td> 
          <td>60</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>9</td> 
          <td>Кислань Сергей</td> 
          <td>59</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>10</td> 
          <td>Кулага Илья</td> 
          <td>59</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td>11</td> 
          <td>Коваленко Геннадий</td> 
          <td>50</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>12</td> 
          <td>Гусаров Алексей</td> 
          <td>45</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>13</td> 
          <td>Вареник Ян</td> 
          <td>41</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>14</td> 
          <td>Молочный Леонид</td> 
          <td>45</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>15</td> 
          <td>Ситалов Константин</td> 
          <td>36</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>16</td> 
          <td>Сапрыкин Владимир</td> 
          <td>35</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>17</td> 
          <td>Бекяров Северин</td> 
          <td>32</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>18</td> 
          <td>Архиреев Сергей</td> 
          <td>30</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>19</td> 
          <td>Литвинов Алексей</td> 
          <td>28</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>20</td> 
          <td>Шевченко Павел</td> 
          <td>25</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>21</td> 
          <td>Тутаев Андрей</td> 
          <td>23</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>22</td> 
          <td>Петренко Вадим</td> 
          <td>20</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>23</td> 
          <td>Станицо Лоренцо</td> 
          <td>17</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>24</td> 
          <td>Явников Максим</td> 
          <td>16</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>25</td> 
          <td>Наумов Сергей</td> 
          <td>14</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>26</td> 
          <td>Курбанов Эльчин</td> 
          <td>14</td> 
        </tr>
         <tr> 
          <td>27</td> 
          <td>Кошевой Евгений</td> 
          <td>11</td> 
        </tr>
         <tr> 
          <td>28</td> 
          <td>Сергиенко Евгений</td> 
          <td>10</td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </div>
```

Мне нужно, что бы в файле index.html отображалось топ10 с этого файла.

Comment: объясните, что значит "автоматически"

Comment: Просто генерить эту таблицу на основе парсинга `rating.html`, не?

Comment: Автоматически - это что бы мне не было необходимо копировать топ10 в ручную, открывать файл index.html и вносить туда измения. Этот файл будет регулярно меняться. Это - рейтинг игроков. Мне нужно, что бы на главной показывалось топ10, а при клике на "показать весь рейтинг", показывало всех игроков. Возможно есть лучше решение, чем делать ссылку на отдельный файл. Может сделать модальным окном или как то еще можно?

Comment: "Просто генерить эту таблицу на основе парсинга rating.html, не? " Как?

Comment: @КулагаИлья использование jQuery допускается?

Comment: @КулагаИлья Как? Как хотите! Как на фронт,так и на бек сайдах

Comment: Допускается любое решение

Comment: @AGS17, ну теперь понятно стало.. Я итак понимаю, что нужен парсинг, но не понимаю, как его реализовать. Хотя бы ссылку дайте на релевантный материал?

Comment: @КулагаИлья Igor уже постарался для вас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("rating.html", function(data){
    $("#rating tbody.selected").empty();

    var items = $(data).find("#myTable tbody.selected tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(items.length, 10); i++) {
      $("#rating tbody.selected").append($(items[i]).clone());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Update*

После того как автор вопроса немного приоткрыл завесу тайны:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTopTen() {
    $("#rating tbody.selected").empty();

    var items = $("#allRatings").contents().find("#rating tbody.selected tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(items.length, 10); i++) {
      $("#rating tbody.selected").append($(items[i]).clone());
    }
}
</script>   
<iframe style="display:none;" src="rating.html" onload="getTopTen()" id="allRatings"/>
```

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/webdeveloper/Desktop/PTA/rating.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4"

Comment: через сервер запустил, уже нет ошибки. Спасибо.

Comment: работает не корректно. Там 28 наименований, и оно показывает первые 10 и ниже весь рейтинг сначала. Добавляйтесь в скайп, я Вам заплачу за решение. iluha0906

Comment: добавьте в вопрос образец файла "rating.html"

Comment: добавил только что

Comment: @КулагаИлья У Вас в первом фрагменте html - вырваный из таблицы кусок. Добавьте полный файл index.html или дайте ссылки на оба файла, чтобы я мог написать нормальные селекторы для jQuery.

Comment: [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4pmvg4N91KpQ2wxaXo4YU53Y1E) Переходите по ссылке. Там еще стоит учитывать, что tablesorter сортирует по количеству очков и нужно, что бы топ10 выводилось после сортировки.