# Нужно, что бы функция JS применялась при обновлении страницы вместо клика

Tags: javascript

Есть рейтинг игроков с подключенным tablesorter(плагин), все работает, кроме того, что нужно нажать на "очки" и только тогда таблица отсортирует, а при обновлении страницы возвращается к исходному виду.

```
    $headers.click(

                function (e) {
                    var totalRows = ($this[0].tBodies[0] && $this[0].tBodies[0].rows.length) || 0;
                    if (!this.sortDisabled && totalRows > 0) {
                        // Only call sortStart if sorting is
                        // enabled.
                        $this.trigger("sortStart");
                        // store exp, for speed
                        var $cell = $(this);
                        // get current column index
                        var i = this.column;
                        // get current column sort order
                        this.order = this.count++ % 2;
                        // always sort on the locked order.
                        if(this.lockedOrder) this.order = this.lockedOrder;

                        // user only whants to sort on one
                        // column
                        if (!e[config.sortMultiSortKey]) {
                            // flush the sort list
                            config.sortList = [];
                            if (config.sortForce != null) {
                                var a = config.sortForce;
                                for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                                    if (a[j][0] != i) {
                                        config.sortList.push(a[j]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            // add column to sort list
                            config.sortList.push([i, this.order]);
                            // multi column sorting
                        } else {
                            // the user has clicked on an all
                            // ready sortet column.
                            if (isValueInArray(i, config.sortList)) {
                                // revers the sorting direction
                                // for all tables.
                                for (var j = 0; j < config.sortList.length; j++) {
                                    var s = config.sortList[j],
                                        o = config.headerList[s[0]];
                                    if (s[0] == i) {
                                        o.count = s[1];
                                        o.count++;
                                        s[1] = o.count % 2;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                // add column to sort list array
                                config.sortList.push([i, this.order]);
                            }
                        };
```

Буду очень признателен, если кто может помочь. Может в документации самого плагина есть автоприменение, а я не заметил [ссылка на документацию плагина](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, собственно, в ответе на ([Есть 2 таблицы с одинаковой структурой. Нужно, что бы при изменении в одной таблице, данные переносились в другую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664188)) предположил, что у Вас где-то есть такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // call the tablesorter plugin 
  $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({ 
    // sort on the third column, order descending
    sortList: [[2,1]] 
  }); 
});
```

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html

Comment: спасибо за помощь, в который раз помогли. А вы занимаетесь фрилансом? У меня достаточное колчиество проектов, добавляйтесь в скайп, буду к Вам обращаться iluha0906